# Find the greatest values of |z| such that |z-4/z|=2. Solution without triangle inequality

Tags: complex-numbers, triangle-inequality

I have solved the problem $|z-\frac{4}{z}|=2$ using the triangle inequality, as seen elsewhere on this site. However, I have also seen an alternative solution, where the user has simply squared the equation, giving $(z-\frac{4}{z})^2=4$.

Solving this gives the same answer of $1+\sqrt5$, so it clearly works, but I'm just not sure of the maths behind being able to use this approach. Is it just a coincidence, or is there something behind the method? I would definitely appreciate someone being able to explain the reasoning behind it.

Comment: You misread or misremember something. $|a|=2$ does not imply $a^2=4$ (though it does imply $|a|^2=4$).

Comment: That's what I thought too. The solution I saw was given as the formal solution in an exam, but I didn't understand the reasoning. Would the fact that the answer is purely real have anything to do with it?

Comment: $|z|$ is always a (non-negative) real number. What you saw was probably something based on $4=\left|z-\frac{4}{z}\right|^2$ $=\left(z - \frac{4}{z}\right)\left(\bar z-\frac{4}{\bar z}\right)$ $=|z|^2+\frac{16}{|z|^2} - 4 \cdot 2\,\text{Re} \frac{z}{\bar z}=\dots$

Comment: I wish it was that simple. The exam writer literally wrote "Hence: $(z-\frac{4}{z})^2 = 4$"

Comment: Then you should ask them to justify that step (perhaps that was what came before "*hence*"?). You could write just $\,z−\frac{4}{z}=2\,$ and get the same result in the end, but that alone does not make it a correct answer (unless you first prove that the extremum *must* be attained on the real axis).